# PIL: can i have multiple sizes of text of the SAME font? (Python)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Currently trying to have the same font for an image with PIL but with different sizes.

Tried to have two different font instances but it didn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: hold up, it is pretty dumb but I managed to do so with two instances, but is there a faster way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [`ImageFont.truetype()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.truetype), you'll need multiple instances for multiple sizes.

You could neatly wrap this using `functools.lru_cache()` so a single font/size gets loaded only once during your app:

```
from functools import lru_cache

get_font = lru_cache()(ImageFont.truetype)

draw.text((10, 10), "hello", font=get_font("Arial.ttf", 10))
draw.text((10, 50), "world", font=get_font("Arial.ttf", 50))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL  import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

# Create a black canvas
canvas = Image.new('RGB', (400,200))

# Get a drawing context
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
monospace20 = ImageFont.truetype("/Library/Fonts/Andale Mono.ttf",20)
monospace50 = ImageFont.truetype("/Library/Fonts/Andale Mono.ttf",50)

draw.text((10, 10), "Hello 20", font=monospace20, fill=(255,255,255))
draw.text((10, 90), "Hello 50", font=monospace50, fill=(255,255,255))

canvas.save('result.png')
```

[image]